# I want to execute a executable with double click in linux, but doesn't work, any ideas?

Tags: terminal, executable, raspbian

I create a python executable in Raspbian with cxfreeze and then I want execute a executable in terminal, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Python script code:

## !/usr/bin/env python

print "hello"

[Image Raspbian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8xdu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

add an execution permission to the file.

Open termnial and `cd` to the folder where the file is. 
After that is done:

```
chmod u+x file_name
```