# Building Python packages for a Raspberry Pi using Azure Pipelines

Tags: python, arm, azure-pipelines

I have set up two pipelines for a Python package. One is for Windows, the other is for Linux. The one for Windows works as expected. However, if I copy the Linux executable to a Raspberry, it won't run. If I double click it, nothing happens and if I execute it using a terminal, I get permission denied. If I build the Python package locally on my Raspberry, everything works as expected.

So basically my question is, do I need to specifically target Linux ARM for my Python app to run on my Raspberry? If so, how can I achieve this? When creating a Pipeline, I can only choose between x86 and x64 architecture:

[image]

Repo can be found [here](https://github.com/LeonidasFettikus/AzurePipelinesWithPython).

This is the pipeline I use for building and publishing:

```
trigger:
- master

jobs:

- job: 'Raspberry'
  pool:
    name: arm32 # Already tried to use a self-hosted build agent, but didn't get it to work
  variables:
    python.version: '3.7'

  steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(python.version)'

    - script: |
        cd AzurePipelinesWithPython
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      displayName: 'Install dependencies'

    - script: pip install pyinstaller
      name: 'pyinstaller'

    - script: cd AzurePipelinesWithPython && pyinstaller --onefile --noconfirm --clean test.py
      name: 'build'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        pathtoPublish: './AzurePipelinesWithPython/dist/'
        artifactName: 'AzurePipelinesWithPython-raspi-$(python.version)'
```

Sorry for not being able to post a Azure DevOps repo, it belongs to our corporate subscription and isn't public.

Comment: Hi, could you share a simple python project and more details(tasks) about how you create the exe. Using something like pyinstaller or what? We need some more details to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok, I added the build pipeline and a sample repo.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically my question is, do I need to specifically target Linux
>   ARM for my Python app to run on my Raspberry?

No, you don't need to specify it to target ARM for your app. Especially, I think it won't make big effects even if you remove that task. If you're using [hosted agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md), it contains different python versions by default. And if you use self-hosted agent, you just need to make sure the suitable version is installed in local machine.

> However, if I copy the Linux executable to a Raspberry, it won't run.
>   If I double click it, nothing happens and if I execute it using a
>   terminal, I get permission denied.

For the strange behavior you met, I guess it didn't result from Azure Devops side. I searched and found several similar issues like yours, see [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178291/not-able-to-run-pyinstaller-executable-on-linux), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700760/on-ubuntu-an-executable-created-with-pyinstaller-doesnt-run), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346803/pyinstaller-executable-doesnt-run-in-ubuntu-18-04-1), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386705/i-want-to-execute-a-executable-with-double-click-in-linux-but-doesnt-work-any).

So I would think that it's more like a common issue in Linux environment, try using terminal to execute that program after using `chmod u+x file_name` to give the file the permission to run. Also, you can use [file xx.exe](https://askubuntu.com/a/613955) to check if the exe is generated correctly for Linux if the issue persists. Hope all above gives a correct direction to resolve your issue.